# Rust Docker Container /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version GLIBC_2.29 not found

Tags: docker, rust, dockerfile, rust-rocket

I'm trying to build a docker container for my hello world rust application. I'm on a less than a week old Macbook pro w/M2-Pro chip and I'm getting this error when attempting to run my container.

```
/target/release/MY_APP_NAME: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /target/release/MY_APP_NAME)
```

Here is my Dockerfile taken from this [tutorial](https://www.koyeb.com/tutorials/deploy-a-rust-web-app-with-rocket). I've tried several different tutorials and all end up with the same error.

```
FROM rust:1.71 AS builder
COPY . .
RUN cargo build --release

FROM debian:buster-slim
COPY --from=builder ./target/release/MY_APP_NAME ./target/release/MY_APP_NAME
CMD ["/target/release/MY_APP_NAME"]
```

I have a single dependency

```
[dependencies]
rocket = "=0.5.0-rc.3"
```

Everything I've found regarding this error is related to installing libc or libb or something similar all of which `brew` complains it can't find. Is the issue that it's attempting to pull a binary the container thinks it needs that doesn't exist on my system? Shouldn't the container be able to pull what it needs from the web since it's its own contained environment?

The output of `docker run --rm -ti MY_APP ldd --version`:

```
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.28-10+deb10u2) 2.28
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

So it currently has version 2.28 and it wants 2.29

I have also attempted to use [rust-musl-builder](https://github.com/emk/rust-musl-builder) but it builds in an infinite loop and has to be manually stopped

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE=ekidd/rust-musl-builder:latest
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} AS builder

ADD --chown=rust:rust . ./

RUN cargo build --release

FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
COPY --from=builder \
    /home/rust/src/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/MY_APP \
    /usr/local/bin/
CMD /usr/local/bin/MY_APP
```

At this point I'm just trying to learn more about docker to understand what's going on

Comment: *"Shouldn't the container be able to pull what it needs from the web"* - the container doesn't need it, your executable inside of the container does. The container knows nothing about this.

Comment: This is kind of expected, though. The `rust` container is a different OS/Kernel/whatever than the `debian` container. They won't run the same executables unless the executables are built as static binaries. Did you try building it as a static executable, with the `musl` target? What does `ldd /target/release/MY_APP_NAME` in the target container say?

Comment: I assume you're asking to execute `ldd` inside the container? I don't think that's possible as the container failed to run

Comment: Failed to run or failed to build? As long as it builds, you can always enter it directly without running its `CMD` ... (like `docker run --rm -ti <docker image name> bash`). You might want to read deeper into docker tutorials, I feel like you lack some in-depth understanding of how docker actually works

Comment: Really, a static build is the easiest fix here, if you can't just deploy in an environment with the same shared libraries you build with.

Comment: I'll look up docker static build

Comment: Not docker static build, _rust_ static build. This isn't in any way shape or form docker-specific; you risk the same problem any time you build a dynamic executable on OS version A and try to run it on OS version B.

Comment: So something like this https://msfjarvis.dev/posts/building-static-rust-binaries-for-linux/

Comment: Yes. BTW, I'm a lot less skeptical about musl libc than the author of that post. Yes, musl makes different decisions than glibc and is more likely to report an explicit failure than silently try to ignore or work around bugs; yes, it's missing glibc's aggressive optimizations to improve runtime performance at the expense of binary size... but those aren't necessarily bad things.

Comment: (in this case your "OS version A" is rust:1.71 and your "OS version B" is debian:buster-slim, just to be clear; if you looked up which base OS if any rust:1.71 is based on and used that -- or something ABI-compatible with it -- instead of trying to use buster, you wouldn't have this problem; but switch to a static build and you're compatible with any environment where the kernel provides the same syscalls, and since Docker doesn't abstract over kernel differences that basically means compatible with every container you can run)

Comment: Please show logs/&c re: the "infinite loop".

Comment: Sorry I already deleted the container/image. The build step ran for about 15 minutes before I just killed the process. I did try it again hoping maybe it was a fluke but 10 minutes later I manually killed it again.

Comment: Ah. When you say "infinite loop" I assumed you had reason to believe it was _specifically_ a loop as opposed to, say, a deadlock or an operation with indefinite runtime for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue was I was using an image which was not compatible with my runtime. To fix I used the below process to create a multi stage build with appropriate containers

I found this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xuqolj01D7M) which I followed. He's using a different web server than I but the instruction still worked. Using this method I was able to implement a multi stage build which reduced the output size and increased security by not using the root user in the container.

```
# STAGE 1 - generate a recipe file for dependencies
FROM rust as planner
WORKDIR /app
RUN cargo install cargo-chef
COPY . .
RUN cargo chef prepare --recipe-path recipe.json

# STAGE 2 - build dependencies
FROM rust as cacher
WORKDIR /app
RUN cargo install cargo-chef
COPY --from=planner /app/recipe.json recipe.json
RUN cargo chef cook --release --recipe-path recipe.json

# STAGE 3 - build source with cached dependencies
FROM rust as builder

ENV USER=web
ENV UID=1001

RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    "${USER}"

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=cacher /app/target target
RUN cargo build --release

# STAGE 4 - build docker image
FROM gcr.io/distroless/cc-debian11

COPY --from=builder /etc/passwd /etc/passwd
COPY --from=builder /etc/group /etc/group

COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/MY_APP /app/MY_APP
COPY --from=builder /app/Rocket.toml /app/Rocket.toml

WORKDIR /app

USER web:web

CMD ["./MY_APP"]
```

I did need to create a Rocket.toml file to set the address and port but now everything builds and runs correctly inside the container.

I have learned a lot about how docker works as well as the reason for builder images and how the different steps interact with each other

Comment: I've updated my answer @CharlesDuffy to hopefully better answer the original question. I appreciate all your feedback